# Which .net 3.5 collection to use for a variable-length array of objects of one type?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I need a .NET 3.5 class more or less equivalent to C++ `std::vector`:

- contained objects type is fixed
- random access by index
- can create an empty container and add objects as needed

earlier I used `ArrayList` and it is quite right except it stores `object` and I have to cast the retrieved objects to the right type and I can add just anything there and this makes compile-time type checking harder.

Is there anything like `ArrayList` but parameterized by contained type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're after [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). For example, to create a list of integers:

```
List<int> integers = new List<int>();
integers.Add(5); // No boxing required
int firstValue = integers[0]; // Random access

// Iteration
foreach (int value in integers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Note that you may wish to expose such lists via [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) or [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) rather than via the concrete type.

You don't need .NET 3.5 for these - they were introduced in .NET 2 (which is when generics were introduced as a feature). In .NET 3.5, however, there's LINQ which makes working with sequences of any kind easier:

```
IEnumerable<int> evenIntegers = integers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

(and much more).

Answer (score 4):

[`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Substitute `T` with your type.

Example

```
// Create an empty List<int>
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Add(4);

// Use the c# collection initializer to add some default values;
List<int> numbersWithInitializer = new List<int> { 1, 4, 3, 4 };
```